# Changing data from via seems to be modifying localStorage object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, model-view-controller

I have a user settings page that loads the user from local storage `$localStorage.user`, stores it in a variable within the scope `self.user` and allows users to modify data through a form on the view. Once the user is satisfied with the changes, `$localStorage.user` is replaced by `self.user` again and voila. If the user navigates away from the page, `$localStorage.user` should remained untouched. For some reason however, changing the `self.user` variable on the view also seems to be changing `$localStorage.user` and I cannot understand why.

Example View:

```
<label class="item item-input">
      <input type="text" class="ec" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name"  ng-bind="{{setCtrl.user.firstName}}" ng-model="setCtrl.user.firstName" required>
</label>
```

Example Controller:

```
self.user = $localStorage.user; // when page loads run this

$localStorage.user = self.user; // runs when user saves
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By nature, in Javascript objects are passed as a copy of its reference. This means that after calling

```
self.user = $localStorage.user;
```

, any changes to `self.user` will also mean changing `$localStorage.user`, for they point to the same memory address. You'll need to copy the storage user instead, for example using angular's built-in copy function:

```
angular.copy($localStorage.user, self.user);
```

Comment: All answers seem to be pointing to the concept of passing by reference. Will keep in mind for the future, thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are referencing the object at `$localStorage.user`. When you do `self.user = $localStorage.user;` you are basically saying that `self.user` is an alias (in memory) of `$localStorage.user`, so changing `self.user` will also change `$localStorage.user`.

How to avoid that? Clone `$localStorage.user`. Example with LoDash:
`self.user = _.cloneDeep($localStorage.user);`

Answer (score 1):

Since self.user & $localStorage.user are pointing to the same Object, modification on one will reflect on the other, so you will have to make a deep copy to avoid that.